# #isolate method not present in Seaside in Pharo-1.4-14557-OneClick

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I have used the finder and looked through WAComponent and sub- and super-classes, but it is definitely not there. I have done a software update.

If it has been removed deliberately, how do I duplicate the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isolate:` is not part of current versions of Seaside anymore. See this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/seaside/issues/detail?id=553) for a very technical explanation.